# Python: Get new list without items in other list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a new list with elements in mainlist except those in other list

How to do below in python 2.7. Is there any fast builtin function to do it?

```
  Input (Mainlist) :[['P', ['not', 'R']], [['not', 'Q'], ['not', 'R'], 'P']]
  Input (Otherlist) : ['P', ['not', 'R']] 

  Output (NewlistIwant) : [['not', 'Q']]
```

i.e everything in main list except two items 'P' and ['not','R']

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Right now your 'Mainlist' is a list of lists (that contain both strings and lists).  So do you want to look at each list in your outer list, and then find the things that aren't in the other list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you have a list of lists, of which each list has some combination of strings and lists.  You want to strip out everything that is in the inner list that is in the other list.

The following code works for me.

```
>>> mainlist = [['P', ['not', 'R']], [['not', 'Q'], ['not', 'R'], 'P']]
>>> otherlist = ['P', ['not', 'R']]
>>> def filter_list():
        newlist = []
        for list_ in mainlist:
            for item in list_:
                if item not in otherlist:
                    newlist.append(item)
        return newlist

>>> filter_list()
[['not', 'Q']]
```

Note that this isn't safe - if you mutate the old list you'll mess up your new list.

```
>>> a = filter_list()
>>> mainlist[1][0][1] = 'L'
>>> a
[['not', 'L']]
```

It was unclear if you wanted this behavior or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[element for element in MainList if element not in OtherList]
```

Comment: Yes, but note that the element of the otherlist you have is 'P', and ['not', 'R'], which are two different items, and it is not equal to ['P', ['not', 'R']]. @ssk369

Answer (score 0):

Used below :

```
def getRemainingLiterals(prop):

    remainingList = []

    for item in prop:
        if isinstance(item, list): #list                    
            for literal1 in item:
                if literal1 not in deletedList:
                    remainingList.append(literal1)

        else:  #str
            if item not in deletedList :
                remainingList.append(item) 

    return remainingList
```